# Optimizing Regex searches

Tags: android, html, regex

How could I optimize these Regex searches? Currently they take up to 5 seconds on my mobile phone

- Conversation: `<div class="field-items">.+?sms-notregion`
- Place: `(?<=de/ort/)[^"]+`
- ID: `(?<=sms-share-id sms-tagline-elem">#)\d+`
- Single message: sms-participant `sms-participant-.+?</div></div>`
- Participant: `(?<=sms-participant-)\d`
- Time: `(?<=sms-tag">)\d+:\d+`
- messagetext: `(?<=sms-bubble">).+?(?=</div>)`

I first search for conversations, then for the single messages in them and so on.

For example I have this website I am matching with: http://pastebin.com/uun0uKL1

**Update**. As it turned out, my regex wasn't the slow part of my code, but the use of Html.fromhtml(), that I was trying to use in order to unescape html special chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't parse HTML with RegExes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2581872) Just don't.

Instead, I've found a nice Java library called [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) which can quickly parse HTML.

Here's an example of using jsoup with what you want to get:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
Elements elements = doc.select("div.sms-tag");
// Then iterate over those elements
for (Element element : elements) {
    String time = element.text();
}
```

And such stuff. Looking at [their "cookbook"](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) might help, too.

Comment: thanks for the idea ... but as it turned out, this solution took longer than my actual regex operations (see edit description)